# Truffle - Error: Invalid number of arguments to Solidity function

Tags: solidity, truffle

I am trying to run a test with truffle.

But I am getting an error:

```
Error: Invalid number of arguments to Solidity function
```

My contract looks like this:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;

contract Leontest1 {
    uint flight_number;
    uint day_number;
    string low_no = "This is a low flight number";

    function Leontest1() {
     //contructor
    }

    function low_numbers (uint flight_number) returns (string) {
        if (flight_number > 6) {low_no = "This is not a low flight number";} else {low_no = low_no;}
        return low_no;


    }
}
```

And my test.js looks like this:

```
var Leontest1 = artifacts.require("./Leontest1.sol");

contract('Leontest1:low_numbers', function(accounts) {
  it("should assert true", async function() {
    const contract = await Leontest1.deployed();
    await contract.low_numbers(5);
    const result = await contract.low_numbers.call();
    assert.equal(result,"This is a low flight number");

  });
});
```

Can someone help me please?

I am using Truffle v4.1.7

Thanks in advance,

Comment: What's this doing in your code?  {low_no = low_no;}

Answer (score 1):

Well, function `low_numbers` takes an argument, which you are not passing it.

Solidity code:

```
function low_numbers (uint flight_number) returns (string) {
```

Javascript code:

```
const result = await contract.low_numbers.call();
```

BTW, you are calling it twice (what exactly is the point in that???):

```
await contract.low_numbers(5);
const result = await contract.low_numbers.call();
```

Comment: I have taken out the line const result = await contract.low_numbers.call();